# Button layout like the <Preference/> button

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, android-layout

I'm fairly new to the whole android-scene so please bear with me. I'm trying to create a button layout like the preference buttons, but I cant seem to get it working properly. To visualize my question, take a look
[at this image](http://cdn2.staztic.com/screenshots/dynamic-effect-101-2.jpg)!

I'd like to create buttons like those, with the image and all, thanks in advance.

Comment: That is a ListView with custom ListAdapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use buttons. Use a ListView in your activity which uses a LinearLayout for each line; the LinearLayout (which is set to horizontal) in turn contains the image and the text. To fill up the list, you use a custom ListAdapter as PravinCG has said. Use an OnItemClickListener to act.

I.e.: The main layout:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/android:list" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"></ListView>
```

The row_layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:src="@drawable/addevent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="right"></ImageView>
<TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"> </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Create a new adapter in your activity (extends ListActivity) - this code assumes you have an instance of a class "YourButtonClass" for each "button" (=row):

```
class ButtonRowAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v= convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi= (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v= vi.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
        }
        YourButtonClass c= getItem(position);
        ((ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1)).setImageResource(c.getImage());
        ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(c.getText());

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return <"button" count>;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return <"button" at position position>;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Finally, instantiate it in onCreate() and add a listener.

```
fButtonRowAdapter= new ButtonRowAdapter(this);
setListAdapter(fButtonRowAdapter);

getListView().setOnItemClickListener(...);
```

There you go.